# How to update Puppet ini_setting or ini_subsetting resource without section header in conf file?

Tags: automation, scripting, config, puppet, devops

I wonder if someone can help me with my conf file problem. I need to get the output like below but I get problems in using the inifile. I have put below my code and testing output. My service won't start because of the '[]'. Your comments and ideas are highly appreciated. Thanks!

**Expected output**

```
cat /etc/service.conf
info something something...
without section header
setting1=value1
```

**Testings**

**testscript1.pp**

```
ini_setting {'setx':
ensure  => present,
  path    => '/etc/service.conf',
  key_val_separator => '=',
  setting => 'setting1',
  value   => 'value1',
}
```

**output of testscript1.pp**

```
cat /etc/service.conf
info something something...
[setx]
setting1=value1
```

**testscript2.pp**

```
$defaults = {
      ensure  => present,
      path    => '/etc/service.conf',
      key_val_separator => '=',
}
$settings = {
      ' ' => {
        'setting1' => 'value1',
      }
    }
create_ini_settings($settings,$defaults)
```

**output of testscript2.pp**

```
cat /etc/service.conf
info something something...
[ ]
setting1=value1
```

Since I really wanted to delete the `[]` character because it's causing error during service restart, I used `section_prefix => '#',`. The first puppet agent run is smooth and working. Problem now is if puppet agent runs on its frequency time (like let's say every hour), it will auto-append details in conf file due to lack of section header. I decided to use `ini_subsetting` but I'm getting errors with it.

**testscript3.pp**

```
ini_subsetting {'subset':
      ensure            => present,
      section           => '',
      key_val_separator => '=',
      path              => '/etc/service.conf',
      setting           => 'setting1',
      subsetting        => '',
      value             => 'value1',
    }
```

**output of testscript3.pp**

```
Error: Failed to apply catalog: Parameter path failed on Ini_subsetting[subset]: File paths must be fully qualified, not '/etc/service.conf'.
```

Any suggestions or advises are highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the file you are managing does not have section markers of some kind, then it is not an INI file, not even in the generalized sense that the puppetlabs/inifile module supports.  To the best of my knowledge, you'll need to choose a different approach to managing the file.

You could consider templating the whole file, or writing a custom type and provider for it, but before going to so much trouble, you should consider whether a good old [`file_line`](https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/stdlib/reference#file_line) resource from puppetlabs/stdlib would be adequate for your needs.

Comment: Hi @John Bollinger, it's a conf file but not having any section markers. The [] brackets caused error upon service restart. I will look into file_line. thanks.

Comment: I went to use file_line instead and I'm satisfied with the result. Thanks @John Bollinger!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried your **testscript1.pp** with `section => ''`?

It would look like this:

```
ini_setting {'setx':
  ensure            => present,
  path              => '/etc/service.conf',
  key_val_separator => '=',
  section           => '',
  setting           => 'setting1',
  value             => 'value1',
}
```

And the output would be:

```
cat /etc/service.conf
info something something...
setting1=value1
```

Or you could try to use `force_new_section_creation => false`, as it is true by default and forces the creation of a section, as stated in the module’s [reference](https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/inifile/reference#ini_setting).

As for your 3rd example, it probably fails because of the blank `subsetting` parameter. The `ini_subsetting` resource type requires both `setting` and `subsetting` parameters to work.

Comment: hi @Éder Gillian yes, I tried the section='' but my output was [] instead of just blank. I also tried the force_new_section_creation => false but my expected values weren't added in config file. For the 3rd example, I've included setting and subsetting name but still having the same error in path. thanks.

Comment: That’s odd. What are your Puppet and inifile version? I’m running Puppet 5.5.17 with inifile 2.2.2. I did a puppet apply on a test machine with the code from your testscript1.pp with the addition of the section => ‘’ and it worked exactly as you want it to: cat /etc/service.conf returns only ‘setting1=value1’. Maybe the newest version works differently than the one I have!

Comment: I just tested it with inifile v4.1.0 and still works

Comment: hi @Éder Gillian it works on the first puppet agent run but it causes append endlessly of settings in conf file because of the missing section header.